# When and how do we need to use 'undefined' as a value?

Tags: javascript

```js
const data = {
  id: 1
};

console.log('name:', data.name);

data.name = undefined; // set as undefined

console.log('name:', data.name);

console.log('data:', data);
console.log('keys:', Object.keys(data));
```

On the above snippet, in data object, there's `name` key after `data.name = undefined;`.

Is `name` undefined actually? When do we need to use this `undefined` as a value?

e.g: I heard that we can use this `undefined` value when delete a item in array. And it will better in performance than `Array.prototype.splice()`.

Comment: You dont need to use it as a value, but you can check for it.  If something is undefined, it usually means there is an error in variable assignment somewhere else in the code

Comment: @Programnik No, it doesn't usually mean that there is an error. The `undefined` value is often used to explicitly denote that a variable or argument doesn't have an otherwise valid value (yet). Representing the absence of a value is quite important.

Comment: @Bergi `Representing the absence of a value is quite important` Good catch! That makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undefined` is similar to a value like `null` in other languages, though `null` does also exist in JavaScript. `undefined` is the default value of any property, or another way to say it is it's the value for properties that don't exist (though a property can also exist but have the value `undefined`).

Use it like you would use `null` in other languages. Generally, it's considered good practice to use `undefined` as the language's `null` value, and avoid using `null`.

Comment: I agree with this mostly, however I would add when interacting with third parties libraries, you might be given null instead of undefined, use null for to signify you INTENTIONALLY set something to having "no value", as opposed to something that doesn't have a value because it wasn't defined properly, or an array search didn't return it etc. Remember undefined evaluates as false, so if you want to find something in an array but it's not within an array, you can do `if (thingWasFound)`

Comment: @Alister On the one hand, I want to say something like "you can definitely write good code that makes use of both values", but on the other hand, I'm not sure if it is or isn't a good idea. I'm getting this concept from Crockford, who advocates using a subset of the language ("the good parts"), and I can definitely see the wisdom in it. The few times I allowed myself to use `null`, I can't say that it was definitely better that way. I feel like if you need to have multiple "missing" values, then you should write a proper type for whatever it is. But it's definitely possible that I'm wrong too.